# Rename files in sub-directories using find and rename

Tags: find, exec, rename

i wish to rename files with single digit numbers by adding a "0" in front, while ignoring files with double digit numbers, for example: 1.fileA, 2.fileB to 01.fileA, 02.fileB, and ignoring files 10.fileK, 11.fileL

when i use the following command, nothing happens. i assume it's because find returns the full path of the filename for which my rename function does not work. below, mediaDir is the path to my folder where my media files are located.

i tried the following but it still does not work:

```
find "$mediaDir" -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec rename 's/^(\d)\./0$1./' {} \;
```

so i tried the following instead, which also does not rename the files:

```
find "$mediaDir" -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec rename 's/^(\d)\./0$1./' $(basename {}) \;
```

although the following correctly lists out the basename of the files without the fullpath

```
find "$mediaDir" -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec basename {} \;
```

i have spent a whole day googling and trying but to no avail. please help.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling further to understand the find command, thanks to Kusalananda who did a great job explaining "find" that "man find" does an incomplete job of:
[Basic usage of -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

In my question above, -exec doesn't work because find returns the full path to the found file, which makes my rename's regex using ^ fail since the digit to be appended to is no more at the start of the string, being within the full path.
Using "-execdir" instead, returns only the filename minus the path; however, GNU find prefixes the returned filename with "./" which defeats my regex. the following finally worked:

```
find "$mediaDir" -type f -name "*.mp4" -execdir rename 's/\/(\d)\./\/0$1./' {} \;
```

Note that the "^" is no more in my regex expression, due to the "./" prefix that "find" appends

To use -exec instead of -execdir, the following worked:

```
find "$mediaDir" -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec basename {} \; -exec rename 's/\/(\d)\./\/0$1./' {} \;
```

It seems that "-execdir" is shorter and better than "-exec".

Answer (score 0):

Use find with regex to match only one digit and then process the output in a loop, executing mv to rename the file.

```
while read file;
do 
   filename=${fil3##*/};         # Extract the directory
   dir=${file%/*}                # Extrasct the file name
   mv "$file" "$dir/0$filename"  # Execute the move command
done <<< "$(find /path/to/dir -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*/[[:digit:]]{1}\.file.*")"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a single line command using find. I found it finally thanks to Kusalananda in the following post that explains find in great detail: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find